# Game Logic Math headbreaker

Tags: math, unity-game-engine

I have 10 objects traveling at the same speed to 5 different destinations in my game world.

The 5 destinations take 5,10,15,20 and 25 seconds to reach. So each destination has 2 objects traveling to it.

My 10 objects all start from the same origin, at 5 seconds intervals. So when object1 is still traveling, after 5 seconds object2 starts to move and so on. The problem is, is that the object's destinations are random...so object1 may have the furthest destination in case 1 and in case 2 it may be that object10 has the furthest destination. In this particular example, I have 5 destinations that each will receive 2 objects.

How do I calculate the maximum time it could potentially take for all objects to reach their destination? Preferably breaking it down in a logical function that captures the above. Doesn't have to be in C# or anything like that, i just want some help in creating a function that could capture more complex scenarios where I have more objects and more destinations as well....

So the variables are:

Objects,
Destinations + Time to reach the particular destination,
Interval at which they start.

For the avoidance of doubt: each destination will receive an equal amount of objects. So the number of total objects traveling is always an even number.

The outcome should be the longest hypothetical time it would take for all cubes to reach their destination (and bonuspoints for the shortest amount of time it would take.)

I have been trying to capture this in Excel to calculate a few scenarions but I fail miserably...

Apologies for the Grade 9 Highschool level question here, but this one has me really puzzled!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum time it takes for all objects to reach the destination:

*The latest time objects start to travel: 10 objects, one every 5 seconds, means the last one starts at 45s.*

**Plus:**

*The longest time to reach a target: 25s.*

So the maximum time it takes for the worst case is 70 seconds.

Comment: Some times you feel really stupid that you didn't spot the obvious. This is one of those times for me....thanks man!